# strtok not printing all parts of string

Tags: c, strtok

i am trying to get all the tokens in my input string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80

int main(void)
{
    char *args[MAX_LINE/2+1];
    char *tokens[MAX_LINE/2+1];
    int should_run = 1;
    char *split;
    int i = 0;


    int concurrent = 0;
    printf("osh>");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%s", args);
    split = strtok(args," ");
    while(split!=NULL)
    {
        printf(split);
        tokens[i]=strdup(split);
        split = strtok(NULL, " ");

        i++;

    }
}
```

why does the above code not print all of the tokens in my string 
for example if my input is "ls -l &" it only prints ls?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with line `scanf("%s", args);`. It reads string up to whitespace. You can instead use `scanf("%[^\n]", args);`. And also change `char* args[MAX_LINE/2+1];` to `char args[MAX_LINE/2+1];`

Answer (score 1):

*split needs to point to a block of memory,
Either:

1) a large enough array, with split pointing to array[0].

2) use malloc near the start of a block, and **free(split);** near the end.

These two patterns are alternatives, don't combine them, as it causes great problems.